# Error occurs when trying to ban user without ban permission

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I get:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: ban_error() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Whenever I try to use this command:
(I'm using cogs)

```
@commands.command(name="ban", pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def _ban(self, ctx, member : discord.Member = None, *, reason:str = None):
    if member == None:
        await ctx.send("Please mention a user.")
    if reason == None:
        reason = "N/A"
    else:
        ban=discord.Embed(title=f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name}", color=0x61187c)
        ban.add_field(name="Reason:", value=f"{reason}", inline=True)
        ban.set_footer(text="( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)")
        await member.send(embed=ban)
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Successfully Banned {member}", color=0x61187c)
        embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=f"{reason}", inline=True)
        embed.set_footer(text="( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await member.ban(reason=reason)

@_ban.error
async def ban_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        channel = message.channel
        text = "Sorry {}, you do not have permissions to do that!".format(ctx.message.author)
        await channel.send(text)
```

I'm pretty sure it's because of my reason but I'm uncertain.

Comment: From the error, whatever code is calling `ban_error` is expecting to be able to pass three arguments, but your function accepts only two. Double check the documentation.

Comment: Will do, kinda confused with errors as this is my first time dealing with them.

Comment: If you're just learning Python now, I would take a step back and learn the language first before jumping into more complex libraries. Using complex libraries before you have a good grasp of the language is a recipe for frustration.

Comment: I know a little about python, I'm just stumped about discord.py so I think I'll start relearning py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: ban_error() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The error says for itself.

You should try implementing 3 parameters to the `async def ban_error`(you don't have to use them all, just make sure there are 3 of them because the library gives 3 arguments.